# Better way of binning data in a group in a data frame by equal intervals

Tags: r, dataframe, binning

I have a dataframe of which is characterized by many different ID's. For every ID there are multiple events which are characterized by the cumulative time duration between events(hours) and the duration of that event(seconds). So, it would look something like:

```
Id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
cumulative_time<-c(0,3.58,8.88,11.19,21.86,29.54,0,5,14,19,23)
duration<-c(188,124,706,53,669,1506.2,335,349,395,385,175)
test = data.frame(Id,cumulative_time,duration)

> test
   Id cummulative_time duration
1   1             0.00    188.0
2   1             3.58    124.0
3   1             8.88    706.0
4   1            11.19     53.0
5   1            21.86    669.0
6   1            29.54   1506.2
7   2             0.00    335.0
8   2             5.00    349.0
9   2            14.00    395.0
10  2            19.00    385.0
11  2            23.00    175.0
```

I would like to group by the ID and then restructure the group by sampling by a cumulative amount of every say 10 hours, and in that 10 hours sum by the duration that occurred in the 10 hour interval. The number of bins I want should be from say 0 to 30 hours. Thus were would be 3 bins.

I looked at the `cut` function and managed to make a hack of it within a dataframe - even me as a new r user I know it isn't pretty

```
test_cut = test %>% 
  mutate(bin_durations = cut(test$cummulative_time,breaks = c(0,10,20,30),labels = c("10","20","30"),include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(Id,bin_durations) %>% 
  mutate(total_duration = sum(duration)) %>% 
  select(Id,bin_durations,total_duration) %>% 
  distinct()
```

which gives the output:

```
test_cut 
  Id time_bins duration
1  1        10   1018.0
2  1        20     53.0
3  1        30   2175.2
4  2        10    684.0
5  2        20    780.0
6  2        30    175.0
```

Ultimately I want the interval window and number of bins to be arbitrary - If I have a span of 5000 hours and I want to bin in 1 hour samples. For this I would use `breaks=seq(0,5000,1)` for the `bins` I would say `labels = as.character(seq(1,5000,1))`

This is will also be applied to a very large data frame, so computational speed somewhat desired.

A dplyr solution would be great since I am applying the binning per group.

My guess is there is a nice interaction between `cut` and perhaps `split` to generate the desired output.

Thanks in advance.

### Update

After testing, I find that even my current implementation isn't quite what I'd like as if I say:

```
n=3
test_cut = test %>% 
  mutate(bin_durations = cut(test$cumulative_time,breaks=seq(0,30,n),labels = as.character(seq(n,30,n)),include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(Id,bin_durations) %>% 
  mutate(total_duration = sum(duration)) %>% 
  select(Id,bin_durations,total_duration) %>% 
  distinct()
```

I get

```
test_cut
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   Id, bin_durations [11]
      Id bin_durations total_duration
   <dbl> <fct>                  <dbl>
 1     1 3                       188 
 2     1 6                       124 
 3     1 9                       706 
 4     1 12                       53 
 5     1 24                      669 
 6     1 30                     1506.
 7     2 3                       335 
 8     2 6                       349 
 9     2 15                      395 
10     2 21                      385 
11     2 24                      175
```

Where there are no occurrences in the bin sequence I should just get 0 in the duration column. Rather than an omission.

Thus, it should look like:

```
test_cut
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   Id, bin_durations [11]
      Id bin_durations total_duration
   <dbl> <fct>                  <dbl>
 1     1 3                       188 
 2     1 6                       124 
 3     1 9                       706 
 4     1 12                       53 
 5     1 15                        0 
 6     1 18                        0
 7     1 21                        0    
 8     1 24                      669
 9     1 27                        0 
10     1 30                     1506.
11     2 3                       335 
12     2 6                       349
13     2 9                         0
14     2 12                        0  
15     2 15                      395
16     2 18                        0 
17     2 21                      385 
18     2 24                      175
19     2 27                        0
20     2 30                        0
```

Comment: can you post expected output?

Comment: The expected output is posted - see towards the bottom of the question. The output is as I want it, just the way I got it is pretty dirty and probably slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea via integer division (`%/%`)

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>% 
 group_by(Id, grp = cumulative_time %/% 10) %>% 
 summarise(toatal_duration = sum(duration))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 3
> # Groups:   Id [?]
>      Id   grp toatal_duration
>   <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
> 1     1     0           1018 
> 2     1     1             53 
> 3     1     2           2175.
> 4     2     0            684 
> 5     2     1            780 
> 6     2     2            175
> ```

To address your updated issue, we can use `complete` in order to add the missing rows. So, for the same example, binning in hours of 3,

```
test %>%
     group_by(Id, grp = cumulative_time %/% 3) %>%
     summarise(toatal_duration = sum(duration)) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     complete(Id, grp = seq(min(grp), max(grp)), fill = list(toatal_duration = 0))
```

which gives,

> ```
>      # A tibble: 20 x 3
>       Id   grp toatal_duration
>    <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
>  1     1     0            188 
>  2     1     1            124 
>  3     1     2            706 
>  4     1     3             53 
>  5     1     4              0 
>  6     1     5              0 
>  7     1     6              0 
>  8     1     7            669 
>  9     1     8              0 
> 10     1     9           1506.
> 11     2     0            335 
> 12     2     1            349 
> 13     2     2              0 
> 14     2     3              0 
> 15     2     4            395 
> 16     2     5              0 
> 17     2     6            385 
> 18     2     7            175 
> 19     2     8              0 
> 20     2     9              0
> ```

Comment: By writing `group_by(Id, grp = (cumulative_time %/% 10+1)*10)` I can get the grp in the same format I was looking for. The only problem is that if say you bin it in hours of 3. It omits rows where the duration is 0. I would like this to remain

Comment: Can you post an example where this happens?

Comment: I just updated my question - see the update to see exactly what I mean

Comment: Updated my solution. Have a look and let me know

Answer (score 2):

We could make these changes:

- `test$cummulative_time` can be simply `cumulative_time`
- `breaks` could be factored out and then used in the `cut` as shown
- the second `mutate` could be changed to `summarize` in which case the `select` and `distinct` are not needed
- it is always a good idea to close any `group_by` with a matching `ungroup` or in the case of `summarize` we can use `.groups = "drop")`
- add `complete` to insert 0 for levels not present

Implementing these changes we have:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

breaks <- seq(0, 40, 10)
test %>% 
  mutate(bin_durations = cut(cumulative_time, breaks = breaks,
   labels = breaks[-1], include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(Id,bin_durations) %>% 
  summarize(total_duration = sum(duration), .groups = "drop") %>%
  complete(Id, bin_durations, fill = list(total_duration = 0))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
     Id bin_durations total_duration
  <dbl> <fct>                  <dbl>
1     1 10                     1018 
2     1 20                       53 
3     1 30                     2175.
4     1 40                        0 
5     2 10                      684 
6     2 20                      780 
7     2 30                      175 
8     2 40                        0
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean up in the code and keeping it in line with my thinking. Is there a way to address my updated issue?

Comment: Have added `complete` to insert 0's.

Comment: Thanks for updating it. I  This too qualifies as an answer but since @Sotos answered first, I'll accept that as the answer. I like how you both used `complete`. I should check that function out.